# How do I fix "expected unqualfied-id before string constant" even when I do not #define anything or miss a semicolon?

Tags: c++, constants

## The Problem

I keep getting the error message "expected unqualified-id before string constant", however, I do not miss any semicolon nor do I #define anything incorrectly. In fact, I do not even use #define.

The error message will only stop popping up when I reduce the number of strings that are entered in the array.

### My Code

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

int main(){
    int score, res=0;
    string names[]="MARY", ... ,"ALONSO";
    return 0;
}
```

***All the strings I enter can be found [here](https://projecteuler.net/project/resources/p022_names.txt)***

Comment: Missing curly braces around the array initializer's elements.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to enclose the string literals in curly braces:

```
const string names[] = {"MARY", "ALONSO"};
```

Answer (score 2):

You initialize an array by enclosing the data in curly-braces `{}`:

```
string names[]={"MARY", ... ,"ALONSO"};
```